# Table centering changes when a border is added?

Tags: html, css

I've been confused for hours at this now; trying to make the table stay fully centred without a border. It seems for some reason that the table centres when a border is added to it i.e. -table.backColor {border: 1px solid;} rather than transparent...

Any help will be really appreciated.

The CSS ive been using is:

```
   body {margin: 0;
   }

   td.backColorContent {
          width: 800px; 
          border-right-width: 1px; 
          border-right-style: solid;
          border-right-color: #cbe775;          
          border-left-width: 1px; 
          border-left-style: solid;
          border-left-color: #cbe775;            
          }
   td.backColorSide {
          background-color: #f9ffe7;
          vertical-align:top;
          }


   table.backColor {
                                        position: fixed; 
                                        top: 0px; 
                                        margin-left:auto; 
                                        margin-right:auto; 
                                        width: 100%; 
                                        height: 6000px; 
                                        z-index: -2; 
                                        border-collapse: collapse;
                                        border: 1px transparent;
          }
```

The HTML of the table is:

```
<table class="backColor">
 <tr>
  <td class="backColorSide">

  </td>
  <td class="backColorContent">

  </td>
  <td class="backColorSide">

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

A link to the example ive been using is here: http://www.nybblemouse.com/external/test2.html

Comment: This wasnt a perfect fix, but by removing the table property: border-collapse: collapse; it recentered the table. My guess is adding a border over-rides the collapse property. Perhaps Im using the wrong border-collapse value?

Comment: Could the problem be with trying to center a table that has the property width of 100% ? What would happen if you changed the width to say 800px? I could be wrong

Comment: if the width is removed, the table falls to a 1 pixel width because there is no margin or width specified. Which is confusing as there is a td width specified...

Comment: give the table a width of 800 pixels or put some content in the <td>. I believe the issue could be trying to center something that has a width of 100%;

Comment: Your markup and css is totally wrong

Comment: The problem I have with specifying a width to the table, is the table is to act as a colored background for another table to be "layered" over the top. For such a case to work, it would require a fixed browser window of 800px. The only other solution I can come to is displaying three separate tables...it just seems unnecessary though.

Comment: @Mr.Alien , may you explain why please?

Comment: See I'll show you how it should be done

Comment: Check this out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35tUf/)

Comment: Like a breath of fresh air @Mr.Alien, it needed a different outlook. Thank you.

Comment: you welcome, I'll post it as an answer for your question so that other readers follow clean markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-construct your markup and apply styles in this way :

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35tUf/)